# How can I find age difference using birthdates in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

```
•Students(stuID: String, stuName: String, gender: String, birthdate: Date, enterYear: Year, gpa: Float)

•Departments(deptName: String, numPhDs: Integer)

•ProfessorWorks(profID: String, profName: String, deptName: String)

•CoursesOffer(cNo: String, cTitle: String, deptName: String)

•Majors(deptName:  String, stuID: String, degreeProgram: String, attendYear: Year, attendSemester: String)

•Sections(cNo: String, semester: String, sectNo: String, profID: String) 

•Enrolls(stuID: String, cNo: String, sectNo: String, semester: String, grade: String)
```

I want to know the age difference between the oldest and youngest student(s) in MYSQL.

```
SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'BIRTHDATE') - MIN(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'BIRTHDATE') 
FROM STUDENTS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*age difference* is the same as the difference in YEARS between the MIN and MAX birthdates:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, MIN(birthdate), MAX(birthdate))
FROM STUDENTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this query will help you

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthdate)), "%Y")+0 AS age FROM student;
```